# Redirect website to addon domain - htaccess

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a hosting that has a master domain and also 5 more (Addon) domains under this same host.
All the websites run Wordpress on them.
I would like to redirect the master domain to one of the addon domains and i have a problem with parts of the redirects, all the pages are redirecting to the right places but some resources seem to enter a infinite redirection loop (wp-include css for example).
the redirection iv'e tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^crossword\-clue\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^crossword\-clues\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.wisely\-chosen\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^wisely\-chosen\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.info\-beast\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^info\-beast\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.crossword\-clues\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.quickinfo\.co\.il$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.israwords\.co\.il$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^israwords\.co\.il$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^israwords\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.israwords\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.israwords.co.il/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect

- www.israwords.com

to

- www.israwords.co.il

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?israwords\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.israwords.co.il%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, saved the day!

Comment: @Raz That was a typo sorry, You can fix that by editing.

Comment: I know but i can't edit it because it's less than 6 characters